# Word count regex that only allows alphanumeric and maximum length

Tags: regex

I've spent the whole morning on [gSkinner](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) trying to change this regex.  It correctly allows only 15 words, but *how do I further limit input to alphanumeric only, and no valid word to be more than 25 characters in length?*

I understand [a-z0-9], but presumably the use of word boundaries seems to confuse me because whatever I do I'm breaking it.

`^\W*(?:\w+\b\W*){1,15}$`

It's for use in javascript/php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this regex: `^((\w{1,25}))((\W\w{1,25}){1,14}|)`

the first word will not be preceded by a space (\w{1,25}), these thing check this. now I want a blank space folowed by a word (\W\w{1,25}), but i want this from 1 to 14 times so (\W\w{1,25}){1,14}. Ok but if the input have only 1 word the second part of the pattern will not work, so instead of a blank space folowed by a word i can have nothing so i added the |. ((\W\w{1,25}){1,14}|)

---

EDIT

the pattern had a glitch if you put - and these kind of character so I updated it to this:
 `^([^ ]{1,25})(([ ]{1,}([^ ]{1,25}|)){1,14}|)`

Comment: OutSTANDing! - Problem solved, now to spend the afternoon understanding how it works - thanks!

Comment: One small glitch - I'm using it with LiveValidation, and after each complete word, typing a space triggers it as an error - is there a way around it?

Comment: I think that this last version is Ok.

Comment: Is there anyway to limit this to [A-Za-z0-9]

Comment: ^([A-Za-z0-9]{1,25})(([ ]{1,}([A-Za-z0-9]{1,25}|)){1,14}|)